# Using Jettison to go from JSON to DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, json, dom, jettison

So far, this is the story of a failure, and any advice is welcome. I tried the following:

### XMLStreamReader to Document using JAXP with Saxon

The code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"alice\":{\"bob\": \"a\"}}");
AbstractXMLStreamReader reader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj);

StAXSource source = new StAXSource(reader);
Document document = XMLUtils.createDocument();
DOMResult result = new DOMResult(document);
Transformer identity = TransformerUtils.getIdentityTransformer();
identity.transform(source, result);
result.getNode();
```

This fails because the Saxon transformer we are using does not support a StAXSource. The exception is:

```
org.orbeon.saxon.trans.DynamicError: A source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource is not supported in this environment
    org.orbeon.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:185)
    org.orbeon.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:29)
    org.orbeon.oxf.xml.TransformerWrapper.transform(TransformerUtils.java:597)
    org.apache.jsp.gaga_jsp._jspService(gaga_jsp.java:93)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

### XMLStreamReader to Document using JAXP with Xalan

The code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"alice\":{\"bob\": \"a\"}}");
AbstractXMLStreamReader reader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj);

StAXSource source = new StAXSource(reader);
Document document = XMLUtils.createDocument();
DOMResult result = new DOMResult(document);
Transformer identity = orbeon.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newInstance().newTransformer();
identity.transform(source, result);
result.getNode();
```

This fails with Xalan 2.5.1 (the version we are using). The latest version is 2.7.1 and maybe they added support for StAXSource in that version.

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource
    orbeon.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:372)
    org.apache.jsp.gaga_jsp._jspService(gaga_jsp.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

### XMLStreamReader to Document using an XMLEventWriter and DOMResult

The code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"alice\":{\"bob\": \"a\"}}");
AbstractXMLStreamReader streamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj);
XMLInputFactory readerFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader eventReader = readerFactory.createXMLEventReader(streamReader);

Document document = XMLUtils.createDocument();
DOMResult result = new DOMResult(document);
XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(result);
eventWriter.add(eventReader);
eventWriter.close();

result.getNode();
```

This one leads to an NPE in Xerces:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    orbeon.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.setXmlVersion(CoreDocumentImpl.java:850)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLDOMWriterImpl.writeStartDocument(XMLDOMWriterImpl.java:583)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:96)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:72)
    org.apache.jsp.gaga_jsp._jspService(gaga_jsp.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

### XMLStreamReader to Document using an XMLEventWriter and Writer

The code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"alice\": {\"bob\": \"a\"}}");
AbstractXMLStreamReader streamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(obj);
XMLInputFactory readerFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader eventReader = readerFactory.createXMLEventReader(streamReader);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(stringWriter);
eventWriter.add(eventReader);
eventWriter.close();

out.print(stringWriter.toString());
```

With Java 5, it looks for `com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory` which is nowhere to be found:

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found
    javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:72)
    javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:178)
    javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:92)
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
    org.apache.jsp.gaga_jsp._jspService(gaga_jsp.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

With Java 6, it leads to a NPE in Sun's `XMLEventAllocatorImpl`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.getXMLEvent(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:82)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.allocate(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:55)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:86)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:72)
    org.apache.jsp.gaga_jsp._jspService(gaga_jsp.java:85)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

### Using BadgerFishDOMDocumentParser

Code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream("{\"alice\": {\"bob\": \"a\"}}".getBytes());
Document resDOM = new BadgerFishDOMDocumentParser().parse(bais);
```

This one gives us an NPE in Sun's `XMLEventAllocatorImpl`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.getXMLEvent(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:82)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.XMLEventAllocatorImpl.allocate(XMLEventAllocatorImpl.java:55)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.nextEvent(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:86)
    com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:72)
    org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractDOMDocumentParser.parse(AbstractDOMDocumentParser.java:66)
    org.apache.jsp.gaga_jsp._jspService(gaga_jsp.java:79)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:315)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think Xalan supports Stax, for some reason. [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) does, so perhaps you could try it instead?

But if not, perhaps you should build a DOM tree from Stax, using [link text](http://staxmate.codehaus.org), like [this article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/06/entry_270.html) explains? Xalan does accept DOM source as input.

Answer (score 0):

JSON isn't XML - It looks like you're trying to parse a JSON object using the XML parser?
I might be misunderstanding what you're getting at, however.

Comment: @RedMage, I'm not trying to parse JSON as XML. I'm trying to use the Jettison library which parses JSON and converts it to XML. You can read more about Jettison at: http://jettison.codehaus.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and went through the same frustrations as the OP. There was mention of this behavior as a bug on a woodstox mailing list somewhere. I was able to develop a solution, however. I wrote a very basic XMLEventReader that wraps an XMLStreamReader, and it did the trick just fine. Two important notes: 1) This code is provided as-is; specifically I have not thoroughly tested it beyond my own limited use, and 2) The fact that this problem is virtually non-existent elsewhere on the internet, as well as the fact that this seems to be a relatively basic operation that Jettison should perform, strongly suggests to me that we're doing something fundamentally wrong and that this solution shouldn't be necessary. Use your own judgment.

First, here is a working XMLEventReader:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.AttributeImpl;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.CharacterEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.CommentEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.DTDEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.EndDocumentEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.EndElementEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.NamespaceImpl;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.ProcessingInstructionEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.StartDocumentEvent;
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.StartElementEvent;

public class WorkingXMLEventReader implements XMLEventReader {

    private final XMLStreamReader streamReader;
    private final Queue<XMLEvent> eventQueue = new LinkedList<XMLEvent>();

    public WorkingXMLEventReader (XMLStreamReader streamReader) {
        this.streamReader = streamReader;
    }

    @Override public Object next () {
        try {
            return nextEvent();
        } catch (XMLStreamException x) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override public void remove () {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("WorkingXMLEventReader iterator interface does not support remove()");
    }

    @Override public void close () throws XMLStreamException {
        streamReader.close();
        eventQueue.clear();
    }

    @Override public String getElementText () throws XMLStreamException {
        return streamReader.getElementText();
    }

    @Override public Object getProperty (String key) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return streamReader.getProperty(key);
    }

    @Override public boolean hasNext () {
        try {
            return !eventQueue.isEmpty() || streamReader.hasNext();
        } catch (XMLStreamException x) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override public XMLEvent nextEvent () throws XMLStreamException {
        if (eventQueue.isEmpty())
            parseEvents(eventQueue, streamReader, streamReader.next());
        return eventQueue.remove();
    }

    @Override public XMLEvent nextTag () throws XMLStreamException {
        if (eventQueue.isEmpty())
            parseEvents(eventQueue, streamReader, streamReader.nextTag());
        return eventQueue.remove();        
    }

    @Override public XMLEvent peek () throws XMLStreamException {
        return eventQueue.peek();
    }

    protected static void parseEvents (Queue<XMLEvent> events, XMLStreamReader reader, int type) {
        switch (type) {
        case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT: 
            events.add(new StartElementEvent(reader.getName()));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT: 
            events.add(new EndElementEvent(reader.getName()));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.CDATA:
            events.add(new CharacterEvent(reader.getText(), true, false));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.SPACE:
            events.add(new CharacterEvent(reader.getText(), false, true));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.CHARACTERS: 
            events.add(new CharacterEvent(reader.getText(), false, false));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.ATTRIBUTE:
            for (int n = 0; n < reader.getAttributeCount(); ++ n) {
                AttributeImpl attr = new AttributeImpl(reader.getAttributePrefix(n), 
                        reader.getAttributeNamespace(n), reader.getAttributeLocalName(n), 
                        reader.getAttributeValue(n), reader.getAttributeType(n));
                events.add(attr);
            }
            break;
        case XMLEvent.NAMESPACE:
            for (int n = 0; n < reader.getNamespaceCount(); ++ n) {
                NamespaceImpl ns = new NamespaceImpl(reader.getNamespacePrefix(n), 
                        reader.getNamespaceURI(n));
                events.add(ns);
            }
            break;
        case XMLEvent.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION:
            events.add(new ProcessingInstructionEvent(reader.getPITarget(), reader.getPIData()));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.COMMENT:
            events.add(new CommentEvent(reader.getText()));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.START_DOCUMENT:
            events.add(new StartDocumentEvent(reader.getEncoding(), reader.getVersion()));
            break;
        case XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT:
            events.add(new EndDocumentEvent());
            break;
        case XMLEvent.DTD:
            events.add(new DTDEvent(reader.getText()));
            break;
        }   
    }

}
```

Next, here is how to use it for the OP's example:

```
XMLStreamReader streamReader = new MappedXMLStreamReader(new JSONObject("{\"alice\":{\"bob\": \"a\"}}"));
XMLEventReader eventReader = new WorkingXMLEventReader(streamReader);

Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
XMLEventWriter eventWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(new DOMResult(document));
eventWriter.add(eventReader);
eventWriter.close();

// test
Source testSource = new DOMSource(document);
Result testResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(testSource, testResult);
```

The output should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><alice><bob>a</bob></alice>
```

Hopefully that helps somebody.